# React: How form submit refreshes page and come back to the original route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am displaying tree component in the left and add_category component in the right part of page. tree node click route to different components on the right.

on page load, page is http://localhost.com
first node click route to http://localhost.com/add_category
second node click route to edit_category

How form submit in add_category refreshes the page and come back to the original route/location http://localhost.com/add_category ?

Please find the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-snow-nfce4i

thanks

Answer (score 0):

for submit handler event you have to use event.preventDefault()

that will stop refresh the page you will notice in your address it shows extra things to use preventDefault and then use

```
const history = useHistory();
history.push("/home");
```

Comment: form submit is on this route http://localhost.com/add_category. how to come to the original route after form submit and displaying the data with node id.

Comment: my question: I have tree on left side of page. On tree node click, it routes to different routes. home page is http://localhost.com. Clicking on node 1 route to http://localhost.com/Add_Category. Clicking on node 2 will route to http://localhost.com/EditCategory.Add_category component is having form. form submit refreshes the page and come back to ( where its showing tree on the left and right on add_category with the way form was the node passing.) How to accomplish that.  Tree is showing here. Please find the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-snow-nfce4i